# How to configure nginx to password protect folders containing a .htpasswd file?

Tags: nginx

I would like to be able to drop a `.htpasswd` file into a folder served by nginx in order to make nginx protect the respective `location` using HTTP auth basic.

I'm thinking of a config like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        root /var/www;

        index index.html index.htm;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        ##########################################
        ############################# note below

        location <any folder that contains a .htpasswd file> {
                auth_basic "Authentication Required";
                auth_basic_user_file <respective folder>/.htpasswd;
        }

        ############################# note above
        ##########################################

        location ~ /\. { deny all; } # disable access to .htpasswd
}
```

I there a possibility of matching a `location` by the existence of a file in its  operating system folder equivalent? And is it possible to derive the path in such a way that it can be fed to `auth_basic_user_file`?

If not, is there another way of realizing a configuration fulfilling the same goal?